# UITableView Header Visible?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there any way to determine if a tableview header, not a section header, is visible?

Comment: Do you mean, if the user has dragged the tableview down like some apps use for a "refresh table" feature?  Or just in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

`-(BOOL)tableHeaderVisible:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    CGRect headerRect = tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
    CGRect visibleRect;
    visibleRect.origin = tableView.contentOffset;
    visibleRect.size   = tableView.contentSize;
    if(visibleRect.origin.x >= (headerRect.origin.x + headerRect.size.width))    { return NO; }
    if(visibleRect.origin.y >= (headerRect.origin.y + headerRect.size.height))   { return NO; }
    if(headerRect.origin.x >= (visibleRect.origin.x +  visibleRect.size.width))  { return NO; }
    if(headerRect.origin.y >= (visibleRect.origin.y +  visibleRect.size.height)) { return NO; }
    return YES;
}`